# $G/ H$ is the Direct Product of Finite and Infinite Cyclic Groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-product, free-abelian-group

Let $G$ be a free abelian group of rank $r$, and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Then $G/ H$ is finite if and only if the ranks of $G$ and $H$ are equal.
If this is the case, and if $G$ and $H$ have $\Bbb Z$-bases $x_1, \cdots , x_r$ and $y_1,\cdots , y_r$
with $y_i=\sum_j a_{ij}x_j$, then $|G/H|=|\det(a_{ij})|$. This is Theorem Theorem 1.1 7. in the book *Algebraic-Number Theory* by Ian Stewart and David Tall, on page 30.

in the proof it is written that -

> Let $H$ have rank $s$, and use Theorem $1.16$ to choose $\mathbb Z$-bases $u_1, ... , u_r$ of $G$ and $v_1, ... , v_s$ of $H$ with $v_i =a_iu_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq s$. Clearly $G/ H$ is the direct product of finite cyclic groups of orders $\alpha_1 \cdots \alpha_s$ and $r - s$ infinite cyclic groups. Hence $|G/H|$ is finite if and only if $r = s$...

Note that according to Theorem 1.16. Every subgroup $H$ of a free abelian group $G$ of rank $n$ is free
of rank $s ≤ n$. Moreover there exists a basis $u_1, . . . , u_n$ for $G$ and positive
integers $α_1, . . . , α_s$ such that $α_1u_1, . . . , α_su_s$ is a basis for $H$.

The following line is not clear to me -

> Clearly $G/ H$ is the direct product of finite cyclic groups of orders $\alpha_1 \cdots \alpha_s$ and $r - s$ infinite cyclic groups.

How we know ***clearly*** $G/ H$ is the direct product of finite cyclic groups of orders $\alpha_1 \cdots \alpha_s$ and $r - s$ infinite cyclic groups?

Note that there is a theorem that states similar thing (see 38.12 Theorem on page 338 of "A First Course in Abstract Algebra" by John B. Fraleigh, 7th Edition), but I want to what obvious thing given in the book of Ian Stewart and David Tall make it obvious that $G/ H$ is the direct product of finite and infinite  cyclic groups.

Comment: It is clear only if you know [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) of a matrix with coefficients in a P.I.D., or equivalently the *Invariant factors theorem*.

Comment: @Bernard I can assure you, nothing of the sort is mentioned in the book, there might be something else, a different way

Comment: The Invariant factors theorem, i suspect, is theorem 1.16. After you have built the adapted basis, the inclusion morphism is represented by a diagonal matrix with $\alpha1,\dots,\alpha_s$ on the diagonal, the rest of diagonal being made up of $0$s. Let me add that $\alpha_i$ divides the following one (they are the ‘invariant factors’ of the theorem I mentioned).

Comment: This is one form of the structure theorem for finite abelian groups, which can be proven in many different ways, Smith normal form being one of them.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan yes I know, but the way author writes, he seems to refer something else, he does not mention the thm.